# How to determine website's hosting company and it's official website?

Tags: internet, website

Are there any ways to determine what hosting company is being used by website? I'm looking for places where I can send abuse. Sending email with abuse to website's webmaster is still (2 weeks) without response.

I'm going to abuse to:

- domain registrator (determined via whois)
- website's hosting company

I know that domain registrator could be determined via domain's whois.

Any ideas/services?

Thank you!

Comment: Normally if just type the server's IP into the address bar (and if it's not a dedicated IP / server), you'll see a page that is related to the hosting company (e.g. an error page with a contact address or even the hosting company's home page). Alternatively use websites like domtaintools.com to find out information about the IP.

Comment: Just to clarify, do you want help *sending* abuse, or help *reporting* abuse?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a whois lookup on the IP address to see who it belongs to, then go to the source of that. If the website is hosted on any reputable platform, that platform's owner should have an abuse policy and contacts.

Answer (score 1):

Any domain should have at least four working email addresses: info@, **abuse**@, postmaster@ and webmaster@... .  These four should be monitored, though it is quite possible that webmaster@... is forwarded to the website's hosting company if those to the actual hosting.

Still abuse@ should be read regularly. Mail there, and mention that you also mailed that when you use @gmck's method. It will make your case stronger.

Comment: Thank you for your message. As I mentioned above - I didn't get any answer from website's webmaster. That's why I'm looking for futher ways to send abuses. Thank you!

Comment: I saw that. Personally I would not be bothered if someone did not check webmaster@ a site, or if they only checked that that once per month.  However I do expect any decent site to respond to abuse@ and I suspect that this is a common assumption with network people. Hence my reasoning that sending an additional mail to abuse would make your case stronger when you eventually contact the upstream provider.